What distribution (if any) are the spectral test values following?
I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but it seemed the most relevant, since my question is about random distributions. Please let me know if I should move it to a different community.
I've been looking at spectral test values for LCG/MCG pseudorandom generators. Between this paper and running some tests of my own on larger power-of-two moduli (in particular 2^64 and 2^128), it appears that there is a consistent trend of the spectral tests in dimensions up to 24 looking similar to those provided in the linked paper. Using scipy.stats, I have determined that as the dimension gets higher, the distributions get closer and closer to fitting a beta distribution, but it is a clearly terrible fit for the 2- and 3- dimensional spectral test results at least. Furthermore, the beta distribution seems to underestimate the "height" of the peak even in relatively high dimensions. A gamma distribution for 1 minus the spectral test values also fits rather well, but it tends to overestimate.
Does this fit some existing continuous distribution better or is a beta or gamma distribution the best I can do?
For reference, the histograms and best fit distributions resulting from my testing with the modulus of 2^128 are included below. Unfortunately, since I don't have more than 10 reputation, I am limited to eight links (i.e. up to dimension 8).







